# remove all options greater than selected one

Tags: jquery

`aselcrumb` is a select tag.

On change I need to remove all options having index greater than the selected one. Something like:

```
$('#aselcrumb').on('change', function(){
    let i = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
    $(this).children().gt(i).remove();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues you have is that `gt()` is not a function.

To work around this you could find the selected `option` within the select then remove all following:

```js
$('#aselcrumb').on('change', function() {
  $(this).find('option:selected').nextAll().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="aselcrumb" size="5">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively you could use the `:gt()` selector with `children()` like this:

```js
$('#aselcrumb').on('change', function() {
    let i = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
    $(this).children(':gt(' + i + ')').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="aselcrumb" size="5">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```